# Function for `fq` field of SOLR in SOLR-node-client

Tags: node.js, solr

For various fields such as `q` , `start` , `row` etc in SOLR we have corresponding functions in [SOLR-node-client](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/).

So if I want to construct a query for the following:

```
http://host:port/solr/eposro/select?q=cats.0%3A1&start=0&rows=4&wt=json&indent=true
```

I can use something like this:

```
var query = client.createQuery()
                .q({cats.0 : 1})
                .start(0)
                .rows(4);
```

However, there is a filter query field in SOLR, `fq`. I don't seem to find a corresponding function for this in SOLR-node-client.

Following gives me error:

```
var query = client.createQuery()
                .q({cats.0 : 1})
                .fq({'brand':'real'})
                .start(0)
                .rows(4);
```

I get an error saying that `fq` function doesn't exist.

Am I doing anything wrong or is there any other way to achieve filter query using SOLR-node-client?

Comment: rtfm: http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/query.js.html
Query.prototype.matchFilter()

Comment: I don't really understand how to use that. How do I construct the query out of it?

Answer (score 2):

`createQuery()` returns a `Query` object and it has a `matchFilter` method.

Example:

```
var query = client.createQuery()
            .q({cats.0 : 1})
            .matchFilter('brand', 'real')
            .start(0)
            .rows(4);
```

HTH

Comment: But if you pass a string to `q` it will be escaped, and if you do the same with `matchFilter` it won't be escaped…

Comment: seems like there is no `matchFilter`

Answer (score 1):

I have checked a bit the source code and found out:

[image]

[image]

So, the usage should be like,

```
let searchQuery = solrClient.query()
searchQuery = searchQuery.fq({field:"tags",value: this.filterTag});
```

If anyone can update the doc, that would be great.